# Can I use pbft with Hyperledger Fabric 2.x?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

It doesn't seem to be supported by the official documentation and git yet.

1. Is it correct that the odring service does not support pbft yet?
2. If you have to use pbft, how should you approach it?

have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

BFT in Fabric is something that is currently being worked on.

There is, however, an [integration](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/fabric/) of [a BFT library](https://github.com/SmartBFT-Go/consensus/) in Fabric which is **not an official Hyperledger effort**.

This integration is planned to be ported into the official Fabric soon.

The paper of the project can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06922) and [here](https://smartbft-go.github.io/paper.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric doesn't support BFT as of now. But work is in progress. Refer following links for more information.

- https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/3411
- https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-rfcs/pull/48
- https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/fabric/Fabric+Strategic+Priorities+-+2021+discussion